# Como abrir um arquivo utilizando php?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, variáveis, fopen

Boa tarde pessoal!!

Estou tentando implementar um programa em que eu tenha que pegar arquivos .txt de uma pasta, abri-los e pegar o conteúdo deste arquivo para armazenar no banco de dados, estou enfrentando dificuldade para abrir o arquivo e ver o conteúdo utilizando variáveis no PHP.

```
<?php 

$extensions = array('txt'); // image extensions
$result = array();
$directory = new DirectoryIterator('C:\Users\Fernando\Desktop\Imagens produto\APPLE'); // directory to scan
$dir = "C:/Users/Fernando/Desktop/Imagens produto/APPLE"; 
foreach ($directory as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($fileinfo->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if (in_array($extension, $extensions, $dir)) {
            $result[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();

                 $conteudo =$dir."/".$fileinfo; //fiz uma gambiarra para juntar o diretorio com o nome do arquivo, para poder abrir em uma variavel com o caminho inteiro do arquivo
    //echo $conteudo."<br>";


        }
    }



}

   $a = open($conteudo);
    echo $a."<br>";
    /*while (!feof ($a)){
        $x = fgets($a, 5120);

        echo $x."<br>";

    }
    fclose($a);*/






//print_r($extensions);

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Você usou mil funções para chamar a extensão no arquivo, sendo que o `SplFileInfo` (que é retornado em cada iteração do `DiretoryIterator`) já tem o método `$file->getExtension()`. Dá para simplificar seu código.

Answer (score 1):

Para ler os arquivos `TXT`de um diretório, utilize a função `FileSystemIterator` combinado com `CallbackFilterIterator`.

Veja:

```
 $files = new FileSystemIterator(__DIR__ . '/files');

 $txts = new CallbackFilterIterator($files, function ($file)
 {
       return $file->isReadable() && strtolower($file->getExtension() === 'txt');
 });


 foreach ($txts as $file) {
      $db->salvaText($file->openFile());
 }
```

FileSystemIterator - Itera com diretórios e arquivos.

CallbackFilterIterator - Itera sobre outro iterador (no nosso caso `FileSystemIterator` e, de acordo com o callback passado, itera ou não sobre determinado elemento do iterador filho.

O callback - Verifica se o arquivo pode ser lido e se é da extensão TXT.

Answer (score 0):

Use isso:

```
$myfile = fopen("meu_arquivo.txt", "r") or die("Impossivel abrir o arquivo!");
// Mostra no browser cada linha do arquivo
while(!feof($myfile)) {
  echo fgets($myfile) . "<br>";
}
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: O título dá a entender que ele quer abrir um arquivo, mas o conteúdo da perguntar dá a entender que ele quer abrir mais de um arquivo presente em um diretório

Comment: "abrir o arquivo e ver o conteúdo"